# How do I get a collection id for flow blockchain nft project?

Tags: onflow-cadence

I'm trying to get information about an NFT collection on the Flow blockchain using this in api docs - [https://developers.flow.com/http-api#tag/Collections/paths/~1collections~1%7Bid%7D/get](https://developers.flow.com/http-api#tag/Collections/paths/%7E1collections%7E1%7Bid%7D/get)

I have no idea where to get the {id} it asks for. The collection I am trying to query is UFCStrike https://flowscan.org/contract/A.329feb3ab062d289.UFC_NFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you want can be found in https://flow-nft-catalog.com more specifically here
https://www.flow-nft-catalog.com/catalog/mainnet/UFCStrike

Comment: There is no collection id on that page though. I need the id for the API call i'm trying to make

Comment: Thr identifier for the collection here is the identifier of the type. A.329feb3ab062d289.UFC_NFT.Collection i belive it will be here.